# i wrote this code to find the largest and smallest number from a numbers array populated by user but it does not work

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am getting user input for function (smallest or largest) and for populating array. Then according to the input function i want to compare consecutive elements and find the smallest or largest number. I cannot understand why and how to fix my code.

The code runs but does not work as supposed to. The smallest and largest numbers are all wrong

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Are you trying to find the Smallest or Largest number in an array of numbers? S/L");
        String functionExpected = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("How many elements you plan to enter? ");
        int lengthOfArray = sc.nextInt();

        // Populating array according to input and length
        int[] numbersArray = new int[lengthOfArray];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter an element here: ");
            numbersArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        // Print out array
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(numbersArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        if (functionExpected.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
            int temp = 0;
            System.out.println("We are going to find the largest number in the array of elements you enter!");
            for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < numbersArray.length;) {
                    if (numbersArray[i] > numbersArray[j]) {
                        temp = numbersArray[i];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        temp = numbersArray[j];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Largest of the three numbers is : " + temp);
        }
        if (functionExpected.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
            int temp = 0;
            System.out.println("We are going to find the smallest number in the array of elements you enter!");
            for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < numbersArray.length;) {
                    if (numbersArray[i] > numbersArray[j]) {
                        temp = numbersArray[j];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        temp = numbersArray[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Smallest of the three numbers is : " + temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You didn't tell us what's the problem.

Comment: I also recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: hint: you need to use `temp` somewhere in your comparaisons

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: You can you one loop to find max and min element in array. You do not need nested loops for it

Comment: Your code does not make much sense, there is no need to iterate twice, you never increease `j`, you ALWAYS break out of the inner for loop after the first comparison and you ALWAYS set `temp` to either `numbersArray[1]` or `numbersArray[numbersArray.length - 1]` in the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Let me think about what you said and try it out. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments the inner loops (j based) are completely unnecessary.

```
int temp = numbersArray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    if(numbersArray[i] > temp) {
        temp = numbersArray[i]
    }
}
```

Just switch the > to < in the if for smallest/largest.

Comment: i wanted to take each element and compare it to the next one and i went for nested loops. Now i understand its superfluous and harmful to the logic. Cleared up.

Comment: @HarishSrinivasan Note that you can look for the largest and smallest in the same loop, and then select which one to print after the loop.